# It is possible to create list of list ReportViewerDataSource?

Tags: c#, reporting, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I want to create a list of list within a table within the report with ReportViewer.

Such as a structure of parent and child.

For each parent can be one or several children.

Visually would look something like this.

```
header 1
detail 1
header 2
detail 1
detail 2
```

Note: There is a fixed amount of Header and Detail neither.

I am using the following:

```
lReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource ("header", lListDados ["header"]));
```

I would like to add details for this `ReportDataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

[This might give you a start](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-working-reportviewer-with-a-complex-business-object-with-a-nested-generic-list-type-property-as-data-source-for-local-reports.aspx) 
You could use grouping fields to order the data in the hierarchy you showed.